# Excel, 1 value contained in other column

Tags: excel

I have list of IDs in A.
B is column with date and it matches column A (every ID has its own date in B)

Column C contains some values from column A (some of those IDs).

Into column D, I need to find which IDs from C are contained also in A and write date from B into D to particular ID.

In other words, I have long list with IDs and dates and another list of IDs which some matches the first list. For those IDs which matches I need to get date information.

Hope it`s understandable, thank you very much :-)

Comment: In every row, in column C you have an ID which is the same as in column A in given row, or it can be ID from other row?

Comment: It can be in other row. This is now working as per Roberto`s advice, now I would need to manage duplicate values in IDs in column A. This will be quite problem I think

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `VLOOKUP` function. Write this in cell D1:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1, A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

`C1` is the cell with the value you are looking for. `A:B` are the columns that contain the table in which you are searching. The `2` means that the result will come from the second column of that table (in this case, `B`) and the `FALSE` at the end is for requiring an exact match.

Comment: Thank you, there was small mistake, because it was looking up in column A and was returning B, thus it was looking ID in dates and wanted to return ID = no matches. After switching A and B it works :-)

One more thing, unfortunately IDs in A contains often duplicate values, e.g. A1 = 500 and B1 =5.1.2015 and A2 = 500 but B2 = 23.1.2015

I need the latest date thus B2 is the number I need to have at D1.. is there any way to do this? Or at least to write all ID matches to one field.. it would be D1 = 5.1.2015, 23.1.2015